# Why is cURL decoding my URL encoded values when POSTing?

Tags: php, curl

When using cURL to send data via POST, if that data string is URL encoded or if parts of it are URL encoded, cURL automatically decodes the data when sending it.

This happens when using cURL in PHP or directly in the command line.

I've tested with 2 different version of cURL: 7.19 and 7.49. Both exhibit the same behavior

I've sent the cURL request from two different servers thinking that the the way the servers was configured somehow influenced this, but the result was the same.

Here is a simple PHP cURL request that I've used for my test:

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';

$data = "https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A8081%2Ftemoignez%3FQid%3D%26"       

$ch = curl_init( "https://example.com/test/webhook.php" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "payload=".$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

The **data** will be sent decoded even though the initial string is URL encoded.

I'm retrieving the data by dumping the POST data into a file on disk using PHP.

Is this normal? Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: Why do you not want it decoded?

Comment: That is irrelevant to my question, it is project specific that the URLs are to be encoded

Comment: Good luck figuring that out then

Comment: $response = curl_exec( $ch ); is probably why curl is decoding the url I'm not sure how you would disable it (if its possible) short of searching php.net under Curl and see if there is an option to turn that part off. I'm interested to find that out as well

Comment: How did you test it whether it was decoded?

Comment: @PeeHaa I've simply dumped the POST data into a file after retrieving it.

Comment: How exactly did you "dump the POST data"? By reading from `$_POST`? `file_get_contents('php://input')`? Something else?

Comment: @deceze I'm retrieving de data `$data = $_POST["payload"];` from the POST parameter and writing it to a file like so: `file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/webhook.log', $data ."\n". PHP_EOL, LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Wouldn't reading from `php://input` instead of `$_POST` actually be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have two different assertions here:

> cURL automatically decodes the data **when sending it**.

...

> I've simply dumped the POST data into a file **after retrieving it**.

It is PHP that automatically DECODES the data when **receiving** it. It is NOT getting decoded upon **sending** it!

This integrates with the behaviour of other values, like cookie data, post and get variables, header information like referrer, ... everything get's decoded automatically when it is received, because it is expected to be sent encoded.

When you want to see the exact data that is getting send over the wires, use a tool like `ngrep` on port 80 to sniff the TCP HTTP traffic.

Comment: Then how come URL encoded data sent with Postman and Hurl.it remains  encoded when received?

Comment: @Remus Triple check what Postman actually sends. It's probably encoding your data for you, so you're sending it double-encoded.

Comment: @deceze I've checked with Postman documentation and it specifically mentions that parameters entered in the URL bar or in the key/value editor will not automatically be URL-encoded

Comment: @deceze  I've also double checked with Charles Proxy. Anyway to triple check? :)

Comment: @Remus You'll have to provide a compelling demonstration. Fact is that data in `$_POST` is decoded by PHP. Your example with curl behaves exactly as one would expect.

Comment: @remus-negrota The Postman docs are a little misleading in the [URL section](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) in regards to encoding. Postman does encode the values in the key/value editor if you select `x-www-form-urlencoded`  but not if you use the default `form-data`.